# есть значения id из одного столбца таблицы и он связан с другим столбцом но в нем нету значений намерено как показать эти пустые значения?

Tags: postgresql

[image: Собственно вот сама таблица и мне нужно вывести значения null]
есть какие нибудь идеи так как мне еще потом нужно соединить эти выведенные значения с другой таблицей но это уже проще

Comment: Ну как обычно - либо LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL, либо WHERE NOT EXISTS..